# Python Check Existence of an Element in Object List

Tags: python

I have an python object list. for example "all_names"
I can retrieve values from that list in this way:

```
for a in all_names:
    print a.name,a.age
```

My target is to quickly find out if a certain name exist in the list all_names.

so I'm doing it in this way.

```
all = []
for a in all_names:
    all.append(a.name)
if "any_name" in all:
    print "Name exit"
else:
    print "Not found"
```

But if size of "all_names" is very huge (ex. if len(all_names) > 100,000), then I think It will not be an efficient way to do the same.

So wanted to know, if is there any more efficient way than this??

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Is storing all of the names in a global list as you're creating the objects out of the picture?

Comment: `all_names` is a really bad variable name for a list of things which are not names

Comment: although `all` is an even worse variable name, since it shadows the builtin [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create `all_name` as 
`all_name={a.name for a in all_names}` 

rest everything is fine in your code.. .

**Note:don't use reserved built-ins(in your case `all`) names**

Comment: Please don't use the builtin `all` as a variable name

Comment: thanks Eric for pointing out that. .  i have just forgotten that user has used that keyword. .

Comment: `all` is not a keyword. I hadn't noticed that the OP also made this mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if any(i.name == "any_name" for i in all_names):
    print "Name exists"
else:
    print "Not found"
```

If you need to find a name only once, this is the way. If you need to find more names - use `set`:

```
names = set(i.name for i in all_names)
if "any_name" in names:
    print "Name exists"
else:
    print "Not found"
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, yes set is faster, but take into account time and memory for its construction.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I beleive the original was actually `O(N^2)`, due to the dynamic reallocation of the list. This allocates constant memory.

Comment: No, the dynamic reallocation of the list is O(N). Anyway I removed my comment since you made a set version.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Then why is string concatenation (instead of `''.join`) often described as having quadratic complexity?

Comment: Yes, string concatenation has quadratic complexity, and so does tuple concatenation, and list **concatenation** (`a + b`), but list append + extend has linear complexity.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
for i in all_names:
    if i.name == "any_name":
        print("Name found!")
        break
else:
    # The loop wasn't broken out of
    print("Name not found")
```

Alternatively:

```
if any(i.name == "any_name" for i in all_names):
    print("Name found!")
else:
    print("Name not found")
```

Comment: this is only 50 % faster than his original approach

Comment: Using a set would require much more memory, although I'd agree it would be a better approach if it was reused.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set.

```
all_set = set(a.name for a in all_names)

if "any_name" in all_set:
    print "Name exists"
else:
    print "Not found"
```

The set works like a dictionary, with O(1) access time. Of course to appreciate the speed of the set, you need to reuse it (ask for several names on the same set).